# JQuery animation to lengthen container not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I want to make the length of one of my divs longer on a button click, however the jquery doesn't seem to be working. Here's the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){

    function extendContainer() {
        $('#thisisabutton').click(function() {
            $('#one').animate({
            height: "200px"
            },
            300);
        });
    }

})
</script>
```

Here's the html, with the code for the button

```
<div id="div1" id="buttons" >
    <ul class="actions">
        <li><input id="thisisabutton" type="button" onclick="extendContainer()" onclick="loadXMLDocTraditional()" value="Traditional" class="special"/></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here's the css just in case.

```
#one .container {
        width: 50em;
        height: 22em; /* Height of the #one section*/
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it is your only problem but if you want two functions tied to the onclick event use this syntax: `onclick="extendContainer();loadXMLDocTraditional();"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need the onclick="extendContainer()" attribute, or the function itself for this to work, as you are attaching the handler rather than performing the action when you call extendContainer():

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#thisisabutton').click(function() {
        $('#one').animate({
        height: "200px"
        },
        300);
    });

})
```

and

```
<div id="div1" id="buttons">
    <ul class="actions">
    <li><input id="thisisabutton" type="button" onclick="loadXMLDocTraditional()" value="Traditional" class="special"/></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Should be enough

Answer (score 0):

I guess [you want this](https://jsfiddle.net/7r3b3xs2/2/) :

```
function extendContainer() {
        $('#one .container').animate({
        height: "200px"
        },
        300);
}
```

And of course, add the relevant HTML in your code to make the animation works :

```
<div id="div1" id="buttons" >
    <ul class="actions">
        <li><input id="thisisabutton" type="button" onclick="extendContainer()" onclick="loadXMLDocTraditional()" value="Traditional" class="special"/></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="one">
      <div class="container">test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Besides, you can choose between the `click()` event in jQuery and the `onclick` on the `input` but both in same time are useless.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because the onlick method is only applying a listener, not calling the method you want. Anyway, you can remove the onclick attribute (and by the way, you have two of them, I don't understand why) from the input element, and use only this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#thisisabutton').click(function() {
        $('#one').animate({
            height: "200px"
        }, 300);
    });    
});
```

This should work. Also you're applying this to an element (with id "one" - #one) that I don't see in you HTML code, so you have to create it too.